# Member "BackGround" is not recognized or is not accessible

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2013, wpfdatagrid, datagridcolumnheader

I'm relative new to WPF and I have check on several tutorials on how to style a DataGrid.  All of them use the same examples but when I try to implement them into my project, came this annoying message.

This is the code I've been trying to implement, I got this from MSDN page:

```
<Window.Resources>
<!-- DataGrid style -->
<Style x:Key="DataGridStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type DataGrid}">
    <Setter Property="ColumnHeaderStyle" Value="{DynamicResource ColumnHeaderStyle1}"/>
</Style>
<!-- DataGridColumnHeader style -->
<Style x:Key="ColumnHeaderStyle1" TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="30"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightBlue"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Blue"/>
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="18" />
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="Click to sort."/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

I'm using:
- C# Framework 4.5.1 
- Blend for Visual Studio 2013 
- Visual Studio 2013 (I got the error in both places).

All the imports and references are just fine.

I have check the solution properties and my Platform Target is "Any CPU"

My guess is this property might be deprecated for this control (DataGridColumnHeader).

Hope anyone could tell the proper way to acheive my goal.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't believe code on MSDN cannot compile. please provide the link. I thought you must have changed something.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.columnheaderstyle(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's trying to use a `DynamicResource` before it's defined.. Try swapping the Styles. Also, there's really no need for a `DynamicResource` here IMO, just change it to `StaticResource`.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <!-- DataGridColumnHeader style -->
    <Style x:Key="ColumnHeaderStyle1" TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="30"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightBlue"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Blue"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="18" />
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="Click to sort."/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
    <!-- DataGrid style -->
    <Style x:Key="DataGridStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type DataGrid}">
        <Setter Property="ColumnHeaderStyle" Value="{StaticResource ColumnHeaderStyle1}"/>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

Comment: I know for fact the Styles order has nothing to do with this issue. i have tried something simpler like:

    <Window.Resources>
<Style x:Key="DGHeaderStyle" TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
<Setter Property="Height" Value="35"/>
<Setter Property="BackGround" Value="Blue"/>
</Style>
</Window.Resources>

Something may have changed between versions because BackGround Property seems not to exist for DataGridColumnHeader

Comment: Property names are case-sensitive. Use "Background" (lowercase g)